# In comparision to

Tags: synonyms, sentence-choice

In my study I need to compare many different methods. Therefore, I need to 
use the words "in comparison to" or "compared to". I repeat these words many times.

My question is,  are there other ways that I can start the comparison?

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus?  https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/compare

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Other ways you can say this are:

> **on the other hand,like, similar to, also, unlike, similarly, in the same way, likewise, again, compared to, in contrast, in like manner,
>   contrasted with, on the contrary, however, although, yet, even though,
>   still, but, nevertheless, conversely, at the same time, regardless,
>   despite, while, on the one hand.**

I Hope these examples help.

Here is an article that may help you further.

> https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/comparing-and-contrasting/